# Reflection - read a property of type class rather than string or int

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using Reflection to read properties and their values of a class. There are Strings, Booleans and properties of a class type. How to get the value of the class type.

User.java

```
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private SupportLangauge flang;
private SupportLangauge mlang;
```

SupportLanguage.java

```
private String languageCode;
private Boolean flang;
private Boolean mlang;
```

I am able to save the data of flang, mlang using reflection, but unable to read value. When I do read, the object is being returned. See sample below.

Result:

```
       "flang": "com.sample.entity.user.SupportLanguage@3080037d
          [\r\n     languageCode=EN_US\r\n]",
       "mlang": "com.sample.entity.user.SupportLanguage@3080037d
          [\r\n  languageCode=EN_US\r\n]",
```

My code below for saving the language types.

SavingUser.java

```
for (User user : CollectionsUtilService.nullGuard(userList)) {
 PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = Introspector.getBeanInfo(
   user.getClass()).getPropertyDescriptors();
for (PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor : propertyDescriptors) {
if (fieldValueMap.containsKey(propertyDescriptor.getName())) {
if   (propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType().getName().
 equalsIgnoreCase("com.sample.entity.user.SupportLanguage")) {
                    String langString =   fieldValueMap.
             get(propertyDescriptor.getName());
             SupportLanguage s = new SupportLanguage();
                    s.setLanguageCode(langString);
                    propertyDescriptor.getWriteMethod().invoke(user, s);
                }                   

            }
        }
    }
```

My Code for Reading the value;

RenderingUser.java

```
               if (propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType().
                 getName().equalsIgnoreCase
               ("com.sample.entity.
                  user.SupportLanguage")) {
                  Method m = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
                  SupportLanguage s = new SupportLanguage();
                  System.out.println("m.invoke(SupportLanguage) " 
                  +  m.invoke(s));
```

Comment: You get the output `com.sample.entity.user.SupportLanguage@3080037d` because class `SupportLanguage` doesn't override the `toString()` method; see [How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you implement the Java Bean standard (i.e. have getter methods with proper names) then I recommend the [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) package.

The [PropertyUtils.getSimpleProperty(Object, String)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.basic) will get you the property you need and there is also an easy way to get [nested properties](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/package-summary.html#standard.nested)

lastly, you have [one neat method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/PropertyUtils.html#describe(java.lang.Object)) that gives oyu ALL properties that have getters into a map

Answer (score 0):

Your reading is almost correct. But you must use the root object (`User`) not the property object.

```
User user = ...; // Initialized user object
           if (propertyDescriptor.getPropertyType().
             getName().equalsIgnoreCase
           ("com.sample.entity.
              user.SupportLanguage")) {
              Method m = propertyDescriptor.getReadMethod();
              SupportLanguage s = m.invoke(user);
              System.out.println("languageCode: " + s.getLanguageCode());
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the java bean API you can also use pure reflection like the following example. the point is to set the private field accessible what may cause a accessibility-exception if the vm runs on a secure environment that has restrictions on that. but for this cases you may can make your properties protected.

```
public class GetPropertyTest {

@Test
public void testGetFLang() throws Exception {
    User user = new User();

    Field declaredField = user.getClass().getDeclaredField( "flang" );
    declaredField.setAccessible( true );

    // get the value
    SupportLanguage flang = (SupportLanguage) declaredField.get( user );

    assertEquals( 
        "SupportLanguage [languageCode=lang1, flang=true, mlang=true]", 
        flang.toString() 
    );

    // set new value
    declaredField.set( user, new SupportLanguage( "lang3", false, false ) );
    assertEquals(
        "User [firstName=null, lastName=null, "
        + "flang=SupportLanguage [languageCode=lang3, flang=false, mlang=false], "
        + "mlang=SupportLanguage [languageCode=lang2, flang=true, mlang=true]]",
        user.toString()
    );
}

@Test
public void testSetValuesFromMap() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> valueMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    valueMap.put( "firstName", "Jon" );
    valueMap.put( "lastName", "Doo" );
    valueMap.put( "flang", new SupportLanguage( "langFormMap1", true, true ) );
    valueMap.put( "mlang", new SupportLanguage( "langFormMap2", true, true ) );

    User user = new User();

    for ( Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : valueMap.entrySet() ) {
        String fieldName = entry.getKey();
        Object fieldValue = entry.getValue();
        Field declaredField = user.getClass().getDeclaredField( fieldName );
        declaredField.setAccessible( true );
        declaredField.set( user, fieldValue );
    }

    assertEquals(
        "User ["
        + "firstName=Jon, "
        + "lastName=Doo, "
        + "flang=SupportLanguage [languageCode=langFormMap1, flang=true, mlang=true], "
        + "mlang=SupportLanguage [languageCode=langFormMap2, flang=true, mlang=true]]",
        user.toString()
    );
}

public class User {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private SupportLanguage flang = new SupportLanguage( "lang1", true, true );
    private SupportLanguage mlang = new SupportLanguage( "lang2", true, true );
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( "User [firstName=" );
        builder.append( firstName );
        builder.append( ", lastName=" );
        builder.append( lastName );
        builder.append( ", flang=" );
        builder.append( flang );
        builder.append( ", mlang=" );
        builder.append( mlang );
        builder.append( "]" );
        return builder.toString();
    }

}

public class SupportLanguage {

    private String languageCode;
    private Boolean flang;
    private Boolean mlang;


    public SupportLanguage( String languageCode, Boolean flang, Boolean mlang ) {
        super();
        this.languageCode = languageCode;
        this.flang = flang;
        this.mlang = mlang;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        builder.append( "SupportLanguage [languageCode=" );
        builder.append( languageCode );
        builder.append( ", flang=" );
        builder.append( flang );
        builder.append( ", mlang=" );
        builder.append( mlang );
        builder.append( "]" );
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

}